# How to return integer range from [0, 1000) from float obtained from random() with [0,1) with equal possibility?

Tags: python

I have tried using `round(random() * k())`. However, integer obtained is not of equal possibility.

```
def k(): 
    number = random()
    if number < 0.25:
       return 10

    elif number >= 0.25 and number < 0.5:
       return 100

    elif number >= 0.5 and number <0.75:
       return 1000

    else:
       return 10000
```

Must use random() instead of using randint(a, b) which is easier

Comment: There may be an easier way. Change it from float [0, 1) to float [0, 1000) and then convert to integer. Note that round will make it harder to get zero. What might be different with https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.floor?

Comment: i know it can be done in a easier way. However, the requirement is to use random() instead of randint()

Comment: I was trying to give a subtle hint. By change, I mean perform a mathematical operation on the result of random().

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be using random numbers, try the [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) import

```py
from random import randint
number = randint(1,100)
print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
random.randint(0, 999)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `random.randint` documentation it says

```
Help on method randint in module random:

randint(a, b) method of random.Random instance
    Return random integer in range [a, b], including both end points.
```

Note, that `[a,b]` are both included.
In you case `[0,1000)` which is `0<=x<1000`. So the equivalent code

```py
random.randint(0,999)
```